# Прошу Вас vs Прошу Вам

Tags: грамматика

I know "Вас" is the "you" preposition for Accusative case and "Вам" is for Dative case, but I've seen both of these on the internet and I don't know what is the difference between "Прошу Вас" and "Прошу Вам".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only **прошу вас** is correct. *Прошу вам* is a strange solecism — but on the internet, it could also be a simple typo. С and М are next to each other on the Russian keyboard.

Comment: Я сейчас им звоню и прошу вам выдать все по накладной, шкуры, кашпо, крючья.

Comment: @bipll See, you had to go rather far to get an example of *вам* occurring after *прошу* while governed by a different verb. Yes, examples like that bear mentioning, but they're far from even being in the top results when you google the exact phrase. Most of it is pages and pages of what presumably should have been *прошу вас*.

Comment: Sure, I simply invented a _very_ synthetic example. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Прошу вам` is not meaningless meaning in Russian language. Just rarely used.

It's when somebody asks some favor for you.

`Сказал вашему преподавателю, что прошу вам поставить хорошую оценку`

Comment: My attempt to find a naturally sounding phrase: Я его каждое утро прошу вам не докучать, а он опять за своё!

Comment: It's still meaningless as a *phrase*, rather than words happening to occur adjacently. `Вам` is governed by the infinitive verb that follows it. It's like using `я хочешь не хочешь должен туда пойти` as evidence that `я хочешь` is not necessarily ungrammatical, just "rare".